# Set a new column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A    Status_A        Invalid_A
 0       Null OR Blank   True
 1  NaN  Null OR Blank   True
 2  Xv   Valid           False
```

I want a dataframe like this:

```
    A     Status_A          Invalid_A
 0        Null OR Blank A   True
 1  NaN   Null OR Blank A   True
 2  Xv    Valid             False
```

I want to append column name to the `Status_A` column when I create `df` using

```
def checkNull(ele):
    if pd.isna(ele) or (ele == ''):
        return ("Null OR Blank", True)
    else:
        return ("Valid", False)

df[['Status_A', 'Invalid_A']] = df['A'].apply(checkNull).tolist()
```

I want to pass column name in this function.

Comment: Do you need to modify the last column? Aren't you just trying to append to the second column?

Comment: i want to just modify  Status_A column and only column name in Dataframe

Comment: `df.loc[df['Status_A'].isin(['Null OR Blank', '']),'Status_A'] = df['Status_A'] + '_A'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

One option is that when you create the dataframe, you can pass additional arguments to [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def checkNull(ele, suffix):
    if pd.isna(ele) or (ele ==''):
        return (f"Null OR Blank {suffix}", True)
    else :
        return ("Valid", False)

df[['Status_A', 'Invalid_A']] = df['A'].apply(checkNull, args=('A',)).tolist()
```

Another option is to post-process the dataframe to add the suffix

```
df.loc[df['Invalid_A'], 'Status_A'] += '_A'
```

That being said, both columns are redundant, which is usually code smell. Consider just using the boolean series `pd.isna(df['A']) | (df['A'] == '')` as an index instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
def append_col_name(df, col_name):
    col = f"Status_{col_name}"
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : x + " " + col_name if x != "Valid" else x)
    return df
```

Then with your df

```
append_col_name(df, "A")
```

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient way is to use `np.where`

```
df[('Status%s') % '_A'] = np.where((df['A'].isnull()) | (df['A']==''), 'Null or Blank', 'Valid')
df[('Invalid%s') % '_A'] = np.where((df['A'].isnull()) | (df['A']==''), 'True', 'False')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're checking each element, you can use a vectorised operation and return an entire dataframe, as opposed to operating on a column.

```
def str_col_check(colname : str,
                  dataframe : pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    suffix = colname.split('_')[-1]
    dataframe.loc[df['Status_A'].isin(['Null OR Blank', '']),'Status_A'] = dataframe['Status_A'] + '_' + suffix
    return dataframe
```